# Shared code between applications

Tags: c++, git, qt

I'd like to share my model between my game and my game editor. Game is developed in cocos2d framework and it containts c++ and Objective-C code. Editor is done in Qt (developing on windows 7 atm). The model is pure C++(no platform specific stuff).

I've had a similar problem at work and I solved it by exporting the shared code as project and making a repository for it. I'd then add it as sub-project and update it as needed, though I'm not sure if it's possible to add a subproject to Qt. It's actually like a static library repository that is a subrepository to both editor and game repositories, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: A separate C++ static library in its own repo is the answer.  There should be no complication with this (you can even compile it with Xcode and install it into `/usr/local` or something and treat it like a 3rd-party library).

Comment: @trojanfore - And just add it as a sub repository to both projects?

Comment: Not sure about sub-repos (never used them).  I always have separate repos which I arrange as siblings in the filesystem and reference them using `../otherproject/..`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for are [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) (emphasis mine):

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios: you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other...
>
> Git addresses this issue using submodules. ***Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate***.

You can also read more about [submodules on the Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: this, but in my humble opinion the submodules workflow sucks if the submodules need to be changed/updated often.

Answer (score 1):

[Subtree merging](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) is another alternative.

For the gory details behind the `git-subtree` script see [this](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) (in the order of increasing hardcore-ness).

To cite the latter manual:

> There are situations where you want to include contents in your project from an independently developed project. You can just pull from the other project as long as there are no conflicting paths.
>
> The problematic case is when there are conflicting files. Potential candidates are Makefiles and other standard filenames. You could merge these files but probably you do not want to. A better solution for this problem can be to merge the project as its own subdirectory. This is not supported by the recursive merge strategy, so just pulling won’t work.
>
> What you want is the subtree merge strategy, which helps you in such a situation.

The `git-subtree` script (which is included with Git in its `contrib` section in its relatively modern versions) facilitates subtree merges.